# FreeRadius can't get new openssl version

Tags: linux, centos, radius, freeradius

I just beginning with FreeRadius. I have installed FreeRadius 2.2.9 but when I try to debug with `radiusd -X` I got this error

> Refusing to start with libssl version OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
>   (in range 1.0.1 - 1.0.1f).  Security advisory CVE-2014-0160
>   (Heartbleed)
>
> For more information see http://heartbleed.com

But when I run `openssl version` I got the result is

> OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016

I have no idea why this happen. Can anyone help?

I'm using `CentOS release 6.8 (Final)`.

Thanks.

Comment: Use the version of FreeRADIUS shipped with CentOS. Don't attempt to replace the system OpenSSL.

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely that you have installed freeradius without  using the CentOS package manager. The version you have installed is not aware of the [backporting](https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting) activity of many Linux distros and is incorrectly using the reported version number in an attempt to determine the vulnerability state of the system. A CentOS 6.8 system is not vulnerable to  CVE-2014-0160. If you want to check then look at the output of

```
 rpm -q --changelog openssl| less
```

I have freeradius 2.2.6 installed from the CentOS repos on an up-to-date CentOS 6.8 and it works fine. You should remove your freeradius and then install using yum.

If you *really* need to use a later version of freeradius on CentOS 6.8 then you can set

```
allow_vulnerable_openssl = yes
```

in the security section of your radiusd.conf